# What's the role (if any) of the original DNS registrar once a domain name has been delegated?

Tags: dns

Let's say I register the domain name mydomain.com using GoDaddy (or any other registrar). Then I immediately delegate the domain to Azure (i.e change the NS records for the domain to point to Azure's name servers). As far as I understand I would then use Azure's DNS admin tools exclusively to add/change/delete DNS records fot my domain.com.

But do I still need to have any type of relation with GoDaddy (or whichever registrar I used to register mydomain.com)? For example, if I would like to delegate my domain once more from Azure to some other nameserver would I do this through Azure or GoDaddy? Or when I need to renew my domain name, would I have to do this through GoDaddy? Or if my GoDaddy account is hacked, would mydomain.com be at risk somehow? Or would GoDaddy be involved with mydomain.com in some other way I haven't considered?

Comment: When you registered the domain name, did you read the fine prints? You would have sign that you are entering a, typically yearly, contract with the registrar to provide for domain registration services and maybe other associated services. After the domain name is registered, the registry will only accept commands on that domain if they are coming from your registrar, except transfers and edge cases about disputes or new technologies like CDS/CDNSKEY that are very rare. So even if the registry may not have operational consequences for your domain, you are bound by a contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registrar is still key in almost every situation.

- They are the people you pay your subscription/fee for the domain name (normally every few yrs depending on the domain).
- They are the 'tag' holder (in the case of .uk names some info [here](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Domains-Archive/Domains-Explained/what-are-ips-tags-and-how-are-they-used-256/)) which means they are the ones you have to approach if you wanted to move your actual name (and payment) to another registrar (e.g if you decided you didn't like GoDaddy any more you could move to Namesco, or someone else) .com domains have a similar setup
- Renewals and any changes to the account or domain name would go via the registrar - this includes any further/new delegation you might do.
- If your registrar account gets hacked then *anything* associated with that account is 'at risk' this includes the hijacking of the domain name to be pointed anywhere.
- Your registrar is usually the controlling name server (Check the whois records) so any query would hit them first before any delegations you have in place.

You talked about further delegation of your domain; so presuming one day you decide to move from Azure to AWS (say) then you would go back to your registrar portal and update the `NS` records to point to your new IP(s) on your new host.

You can either you manage all your DNS via your registrar, or delegate the `NS` records (as you have already) and run your own DNS Server. In your setup you use the Azure (or whatever) tools to manage your actual records, but you would need to go back to the registrar to manage the `NS` records that controlled the delegation of the domain. You should note that not all registrar will allow the delegation of `NS` records and in effect 'force' you to use there own portal/DNS tools so check carefully.

> The short of it is - you still have and must maintain any relationship
>   with the registrar.

Comment: "You should note that not all registrar will allow the delegation of NS records" at least in the gTLD world, this is strictly forbidden, registrars have to push to registries the values of nameservers the registrant wants to have.